# ConfigurationManager exists in both System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager and in System.Configuration

Tags: c#, .net-standard

I'm working on porting one of our common libraries over to NET Standard 2.0.

There are several areas where the existing library uses the old ConfigurationManager to access the app.config file.

I've added in the pre-release version of System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager which is resolving fine when netstandard 2.0 is selected. But when I select net461 its throwing an error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0433  The type 'ConfigurationManager' exists in both 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' and 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Synovia.Service.Common.Core(net461) C:\git\synovia.service.common\Common\EmailHelper.cs 15  Active
```

Looking through my references I dont see where I am referencing both. Has anyone encountered this and what did you do to resolve it?

All attempts at Searching for answers keeps resulting in .NET 2.0 answers etc.

**EDIT - CURRENT REFERENCES** As you can see I'm not referencing System.Configuration where. Just the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ALK.Core" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Core" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Core" Version="3.3.14.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Lambda" Version="3.3.6.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.S3" Version="3.3.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.SimpleNotificationService" Version="3.3.0.17" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.SimpleWorkflow" Version="3.3.0.17" />
    <PackageReference Include="DogStatsD-CSharp-Client" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdeaBlade.DevForce.Core" Version="7.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="JetBrains.Annotations" Version="10.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Log4Net.Async.Standard" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" Version="14.0.314.76" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moneris" Version="3.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="protobuf-net" Version="2.3.0-alpha" />
    <PackageReference Include="PushSharp" Version="2.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="RabbitMQ.Client" Version="4.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="RabbitMqConsumers" Version="1.0.20" />
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack" Version="4.5.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Text" Version="4.5.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis" Version="1.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.4.0-preview1-25305-02" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.Common" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.4.0-preview1-25305-02" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Linq" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Threading" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Threading.Tasks" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" Version="4.4.0-preview1-25305-02" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Threading.Thread" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Threading.Timer" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Xml.XDocument" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Xml.XmlDocument" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Xml.XmlSerializer" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Telogis.Geobase" Version="4.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: If you don't get an answer, just use conditionals to get around the error.  Rick Strahl just this morning posted on the subject.  Go take a peek at how he did this in a multitargeting project.

Comment: If you are working on a .NET Standard project, then the reference list should not contain `System.Configuration`.

Comment: @LexLi - I've updated with my list of references. I'm not referencing System.Configuration anywhere. Also of note is this project targets both net461 and netstandard20

Comment: The current list you show has many issues. 1. Don't mix 4.3.0 and 4.4.0 preview. 2. Use `NETStandard.Library` to simplify the list. 3. All dependencies should support .NET Standard, and you have to check them one by one, or they would pollute the compilation.

Comment: @LexLi I'm not sure how you propose getting around mixing 4.30 with 4.4 preview stuff when they dont have 4.4 preview releases out for things such as System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel and I need access things in System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.

Comment: @Will I think following Rick's guidance will get me where I need to be - here is the blog link just for reference:

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Jun/22/MultiTargeting-and-Porting-a-NET-Library-to-NET-Core-20

Comment: My guess is one of the other dependencies is referencing System.Configuration, I cant see how else it would be causing a conflict considering I'm not referencing it anywhere explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got this working. All the suggestions made helped me in the right direction. The main problems were I had a reference that was trying to pull the wrong System.Configuration. Once I sorted all that out I added this into my csproj

```
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461' ">        
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0' ">
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.4.0-preview1-25305-02" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I had originally tried this but it wasnt working b/c I typed 'netstandard20' instead of 'netstandard2.0' ....

Oh well its working now, thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the other dependencies in this list but your referencing ServiceStack's .NET Framework dependencies here:

```
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack" Version="4.5.12" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Text" Version="4.5.12" />
```

Which do have a dependency on System.Configuration. To reference ServiceStack's .NET Standard packages you need to instead reference:

```
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Core" Version="1.0.43" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Text.Core" Version="1.0.43" />
```

If you're targeting both .NET Framework and .NET Standard you'll need to reference the both of these dependencies under their respective platforms.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the reference to just use the new Core version, but I'm still having the same issue. Think I may just need to head over to the net standard github page and ask what they suggest.

Comment: @Wjdavis5 you'd also need to do the same check on each of your dependencies to make sure each of them is referencing a NuGet package that has .NET Standard DLLs

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did the following :

1. Clean solution.
2. Go to solution folder
3. Deleted the bin and obj folder
4. Rebuild the solution

Everything worked fine after this.